# How to interpret two graphs/data with the same mean but different standard deviation?

Tags: regression, time-series, mean, standard-deviation

[image]

I have two lines with the same average, but has more fluctuation, do i analyse them in the same way and make conclusion?

Basically i need some advice on how i would look at these graphs. Should I use standard deviation to analyse fluctuation or median instead of mean?

or can i just say they are both increasing?

Comment: They are different populations so you would compare them in the same way. It would be like comparing economic activity in the US to say France. What are you looking at these graphs for?

Comment: Incidentally, having missed this before, you could say (without comparing one to the other) that they were increasing. You could do a formal test of stationarity in fact (like augmented dickey fuller) and calculate a rate of increase.